# Admin account not in sudoers

Tags: sudo, administrator

On my MacBook (OS 12.6.1) I have a primary account and a secondary one, which is an admin. In the terminal, I can `su` into the secondary one. However, if I try to use `sudo` then, I see that the admin account is somehow not listed as a sudoer.

The Mac is is a work one. There could be corporate intervention for all I know.

Is there any way to restore the sudo rights using the admin powers alone (i. e. without using the terminal)?

Comment: If a corporate machine ask your IT support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably corporate interference.

Created a brand new admin user, that one was in sudoers right away, used that new admin to edit the sudoers file and re-add the original designated admin account.

Comment: There's probably a good reason for IT to not allow employees to use sudo on company-owned machines.  The fact that they missed the loophole you fond doesn't reduce your risk for taking advantage of it.  Whatever you needed (wanted) sudo for, should have been requested from IT.